# Inno Setup ISPP, how to define Processor Architecture...?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying define a x86 x64 preprocessor variable in Inno Setup with this code, but it doesn´t work:

```
#if IsWin64
 #define OSBITS "x64"
#else
 #define OSBITS "x86"
#endif
```

Can someone help me to define `OSBITS`?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#if` is a preprocessor directive. As such, it is evaluated on compile-time. You cannot use it to select a value based on target's machine architecture as that is known on runtime (install-time) only.

For this reason there's even no `IsWin64` preprocessor function.

---

If you need to use the x64/x86 value in some Inno Setup directive, you can usually use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants).

A simple example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program {code:OSBits}

[Code]

function OSBits(Param: String): string;
begin
  if IsWin64 then
    Result := 'x64'
  else
    Result := 'x86';
end;
```